# Poisson Calc with high factorial

Tags: java, poisson

i have this piece of Code for the calc:

```
    public static double CalcPoisson(double m, double u, boolean va)
{
    double answer = 0;
    if(!va)
    {
        answer = (Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m)) / (factorial(m));
    }
    if(va)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            answer = answer + (Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, i)) / (factorial(i));
        }
    }

    return answer;
```

And this was my factorial method

```
    public static double factorial (double n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n *factorial(n-1);
}
```

Problem is: the maximum value to calculate is 170...i need way more (like factorial of 500)

I have written a new Method:

```
    public static BigDecimal factorial2 (double n)
{
    BigDecimal fct = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fct = fct.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i));
    }

    return fct;
```

How can i use my new factorialmethod in my "CalcPoisson" Method?
Problem is, i cant divide double with BigDecimal...

Thanks for the help :)

For No One:

I have still this Line of Code in one method that uses CalcPoisson, im still bad with BigDecimal, i cant handle it.

The Line:

```
        BigDecimal nenner = CalcPoisson(m, u, false) + (1-p) * CalcPoisson(m, u, true);
```

Comment: What wasn't working with `double`?  Everything, including your final result, is double precision, if you need more than that one `BigDecimal` value stuck in the middle of your equation isn't going to help.

Comment: Problem is the method factorial just works till 170!  So the idea is, to use everywhere BigDecimal instead of double?

Comment: is (1-p) is BigDecimal?

Comment: I mean `p` is BigDecimal ?

Comment: @T.Setso  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Says me the Line:             answer = myOwn.divide(factorial2(m));    is wrong,

Comment: the Line:                 answer = answer.add(myOwn2.divide(factorial2(i))); is wrong aswell (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.)

Comment: i found the error and fixxed it.. Thanks for your help. It helped my alot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert your double to `BigDecimal` and then you can divide two `BigDecimal`s as following:

```
BigDecimal answer = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal myOwn = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, i)));
answer = answer.add(myOwn.divide(factorial2(i)));
```

Use `BigDecimal` to find Factorial as you have done in `factorial2()`.

Finally your method will look like:

```
    public static BigDecimal CalcPoisson(double m, double u, boolean va)
{
BigDecimal answer = BigDecimal.ZERO;
if(!va)
{
    BigDecimal myOwn1 = new BigDecimal(Double.toString((Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, m))));
    answer =  myOwn1.divide(fakultaet(m));
}
if(va)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        BigDecimal myOwn = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, i)));
        answer = answer.add(myOwn.divide(factorial2(i)));
    }
}

return answer;
```

Assuming that you have return type of method `fakultaet()` is BigDecimal. And if you have return value `double` for the same, than try:

```
answer =  myOwn1.divide(new BigDecimal(fakultaet(m)));
```

**EDIT**

```
BigDecimal nenner = CalcPoisson(m, u, false).add((BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal(p))).multiply( CalcPoisson(m, u, true)));
```

Comment: @T.Setso You are welcome :) You can mark the answer as correct if it is helpful :)

Comment: Another problem: One Line of another method is: 'BigDecimal nenner = calcPoisson(m, u, false) + (1-p) * calcPoisson(m, u, true);' the problem is now, * isnt defined for BigDecimal

Comment: Wherever you see star (*), You can use, .multiply() for BigDecimal and BigInteger both.

Comment: If you still getting error, post that method in question. I'll try to help. @T.Setso

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    answer = answer + (Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, i)) / (factorial(i));
}
```

Note that this algorithm computes all factorials from 0 through m-1. Much faster and more accurate to factor that out:

```
   long fact = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        answer = answer + (Math.exp(-u)* Math.pow(u, i)) / fact;
        fact *= (i+1);
    }
```

then  note that Math.exp(-u) is invariant in the loop, so extract it:

```
long fact = 1;
double eu = Math.exp(-u);
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    answer = answer + (eu * Math.pow(u, i)) / fact;
    fact *= (i+1);
}
```

And you can also get rid of the repeated calls to Math.pow():

```
long fact = 1;
double eu = Math.exp(-u);
double term = u;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    answer = answer + (eu * term) / fact;
    fact *= (i+1);
    term *= u;
}
```

Finally, you can also get combine term and fact into a single parameter (left as an exercise for the student).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i know my algorithm is coded bad.. And i'll try to learn to do it better :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new BigDecimal out of the Double
Then you can use the multiplie method of the BigDecimal

```
fct = fct.multiplie(new BigDecimal(doubleValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is too direct. Such loops are usually written in terms of `while (nextTerm < epsilon)` , not as a for loop. That is, of course, provided that you can prove that the terms do decrease with `i`.

The other problem is that while the value of the expression `pow(u,i) / factorial(i)` may fit in a double, its parts surely do not. You need to compute this in a different way. Of course, as you do, you lose precision, so it becomes even more complicated.

I should better stop. My Math professor promised that he will hunt down and kill any of us who tried to do computational math, and he was a serious gentleman.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i know my algorithm is coded bad.. And i'll try to learn to do it better :)